# Proof of covariant convolution for a kernel function that is rotation symmetric in Fourier space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, integration, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

## Problem Statement

Let $g:\mathbb R^{d}\to \mathbb R,d\in\{2,3\}$ be an integrable function (assumption **I1**). Suppose $\mathcal T$ is a rotation, and $f:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb C$ (assumption **C**) is an integrable function (assumption **I2**) such that $\mathcal T\mathcal F f=\mathcal F f$ (assumption **S**). Finally, let assumption(s) **U** be some further, unknown restrictions on $\mathcal T$, $f$, and $g$. Then, I would like to prove the following:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal F^{-1}\left(\mathcal Ff\cdot\mathcal F\mathcal Tg\right)=\mathcal T\mathcal F^{-1}\left(\mathcal Ff\cdot\mathcal Fg\right). \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

From the convolution theorem, the following is equivalent:

\begin{equation}
f*\left(\mathcal Tg\right)=\mathcal T\left(f*g\right).
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

In words, this says that if the convolution kernel $f$ is invariant to rotations in Fourier space, then the convolution is equivariant to rotations, i.e., rotating $g$ and then performing the convolution gives the same result as performing the convolution and then rotating the result.

My question is to define **U** and show how these assumptions can be used to prove equation \eqref{1}.

## Assumptions

I will now summarize the motivation for each assumption. I believe each to be necessary to prove this result.

### Assumption **I1** and **I2**

From the convolution theorem:

$$
\mathcal F^{-1}\left(\mathcal Ff\cdot\mathcal Fg\right)=f*g.
$$

If $f$ and $g$ are integrable, then the convolution is defined ([[source]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519034/show-that-convolution-of-two-measurable-functions-is-well-defined)).

### Assumption **C**

Since the transform of a real-valued function is Hermitian, and Hermitian functions are not invariant to rotations, $f$ must be complex-valued to satisfy assumption **S**.

### Assumption **S**

Empirically, I have observed that this is a necessary assumption for equation \eqref{1} to be achieved. In my experiments for $d=2$ ($d=3$), $\mathcal T$ is replaced with $90^\circ$ rotations, $\mathcal F$ is replaced with the discrete Fourier transform in 2 (3) dimensions, and $f$ and $g$ are matrices ($3$-dimensional tensors).

Comment: I think by "For this convolution to be defined, both $f$ and $g$ must be integrable" you mean "If $f$ and $g$ are both integrable, then the convolution is defined", or maybe "The convolution is not always defined, but it is if $f$ and $g$ are both integrable" (which is what your link shows).  For example, if one of $f$ or $g$ is $0$, then the convolution is defined regardless of the integrability of the other.

Comment: I was thinking that this could lead to infinity times zero. I will edit, though. Thanks

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437032/proof-of-rotation-equivariance-of-convolution-for-a-kernel-function-that-is-rota#comment1126754_437032), measure-theoretic $0\cdot\infty$ is usually $0$, so that $\infty\chi_A$ and $0\chi_B$ are both correctly given integral $0$ when $A$ has measure $0$ and $B$ has measure $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that no extra assumption **U** is needed, assumption **S** suffices. The key thing to observe is that the Fourier transform of a rotated function is equal to a rotated version of the Fourier transform of that function, see for example [Appendix A: Rotation property of Fourier transforms](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm:978-1-4613-1333-5/1.pdf) of the book [Jakowatz, Wahl, Eichel, Ghiglia, and Thompson - Spotlight-Mode Synthetic Aperture Radar: A Signal Processing Approach](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-1333-5) for a proof.

Denote by $R$ the operation that rotates the vector $x$, then assumption **S** that $\mathcal T\mathcal F f=\mathcal F f$ implies that $f(Rx)=f(x)$. Now apply this to the convolution,
$$(f\ast {\cal T}g)(x)=\int dz\, f(x-z)g(Rz)=\int dz\, f(Rx-Rz)g(Rz)$$
$$=\int dRz\, f(Rx-Rz)g(Rz)=(f\ast g)(Rx)={\cal T}(f\ast g)(x),$$
which is the desired identity. (When switching from $z$ to $Rz$ as integration variable I have used that the Jacobian for this transformation is unity.)

Comment: Please let me know if I have misunderstood how you arrived at your first step. First, the rotation property of the Fourier transform says that if I rotate the physical domain, then the frequency domain rotates equally: 

$$\mathcal F \mathcal Tf(x)[\xi] = \mathcal F \mathcal f(Rx)[\xi] = \mathcal F \mathcal f(x)[R\xi]= \mathcal T\mathcal F \mathcal f(x)[\xi]$$ 

Therefore: 

$$\mathcal F \mathcal Tf(x)[\xi] = \mathcal T\mathcal F \mathcal f(x)[\xi] = \mathcal F \mathcal f(x)[\xi]$$ 

The last equality is from assumption **S**.

Comment: Finally, from the uniqueness of the transform \[[source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569948/uniqueness-of-fourier-transform-in-l1?noredirect=1&lq=1)\]

$$\mathcal F \mathcal Tf(x)[\xi] = \mathcal F \mathcal f(x)[\xi]\iff \mathcal Tf=f, a.e.$$

Comment: yes, that is how I understand it.

Comment: Based on my understanding, for all $f$, the rotation property says that:

$$
\mathcal T\mathcal F f =\mathcal F\mathcal T f
$$

I also believe that the only way $\mathcal T\mathcal F f=\mathcal F f$ is if $f$ is complex valued, since if $f$ is real, $\mathcal F f$ will be Hermitian and therefore cannot have rotation symmetry.

Both of these seem to not be true though. Suppose $f$ is real-valued and $\mathcal Tf=f$. Then:

$$
\mathcal F \mathcal Tf = \mathcal F f 
$$

Also from the rotation property:

$$
\mathcal F\mathcal T f = \mathcal T \mathcal Ff
$$

Comment: This gives $\mathcal F f = \mathcal T \mathcal F f$, which is a contradiction to my understanding. Did I obtain this contradiction through my assumption that a Hermitian function cannot be symmetric to $\mathcal T$?

Comment: I don't understand your requirement of complex valued $f$; take, for example, a Gaussian $f(x)\propto \exp(-\|x\|^2)$; it is real valued and rotationally invariant; its Fourier transform is still a Gaussian, real valued and rotationally invariant.

Comment: I think the only way a function can be both symmetric to rotations and Hermitian is if the imaginary part is 0 like the Gaussian (sketch below), but according to my seemingly incorrect understanding of the rotation property, the property $\mathcal Tf=f\implies \mathcal Ff=\mathcal T\mathcal Ff$ holds more generally for any rotation symmetric $f$, i.e., even if $\mathcal Ff$ is complex

Comment: Suppose $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb C$ is symmetric to rotations. Then, $f(x,y)=\Re f(x,y)+\Im f(x,y)i=\Re f(−x,−y)+\Im f(−x,−y)i=f(−x,−y)$. Further suppose that $f$ is Hermitian. This gives that $\Re f(x,y)=\Re f(−x,−y)$ and $\Im f(x,y)=−\Im f(−x,−y)$. Putting these two together gives that $\Im f(−x,−y)=−\Im f(−x,−y)$, so $\Im f(−x,−y)=\Im f(x,y)=0$

Comment: Hermitian is a concept that refers to an operator kernel $F(\mathbf{r}|\mathbf{r}')=\bar{F}(\mathbf{r}'|\mathbf{r})$; in the case you are considering the operator kernel is diagonal $F(\mathbf{r}|\mathbf{r}')=f(\mathbf{r})\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')$; in that case Hermitian is the same as real, $f(\mathbf{r})=\bar{f}(\mathbf{r})$.